# How to find the 'obj' directory for C# projects using Roslyn MSBuildWorkspace?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn to compile a C# solution with several projects in it, using the `MsBuildWorkspace`.

It's easy to find the output file of a `Project`, for that I can just use the `OutputFilePath` property.

But I can't find a way to figure out the 'intermediate' directory (typically this is the 'obj' directory, but this can be changed using the MSBuild properties `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` and `IntermediateOutputPath` in the `csproj` file).

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to find it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm making a "hot code reloader", i.e. recompiling modified code while my program is running (I load/unload all assemblies using an AppDomain). However, Visual Studio/MSBuild often generates C# files in the intermediate 'obj' folders. For example, for a file `UserControl.xaml.cs` another file `UserControl.g.cs` will be generated. Since I don't think Roslyn can generate these files, my current approach is to add these generated files to a new Roslyn `Project`. This is a hack, but works (I'm using MVVM and loose XAML, so I only have a few of these files)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` from `Microsoft.Build.dll` and got project properties:

```
void foo(String projectPath, IDictionary<String, String> globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
{
    Project project = new Project(projectPath, globalProperties, toolsVersion);
    String baseIntermediateOutputPath = GetProjectProperty(project, "BaseIntermediateOutputPath");
    String intermediateOutputPath = GetProjectProperty(project, "IntermediateOutputPath");
    // ....
}

static String GetProjectProperty(Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project project, String propertyName)
{
    return project.Properties
                  .FirstOrDefault(prop => String.Equals(prop.Name, propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                 ?.EvaluatedValue;
}
```